# How to use Power Automate to send an email to a person who has been assigned to the corresponding item?

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I'm trying to send an email to the individual who has been assigned to a project. I used "Get Items" to collect the information from the List and then a condition to check if the email is empty.

[Image of the flow I'm using now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xivw.jpg)

Comment: In the send email shape, you should be able to pick the assigned to field. If it is a list of items it will automatically surrounded by apply to each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my understanding, you want to create a flow to send an email to the item creator or the specify user account if the value of "**Assigned To**" is empty.

You can use the below Microsoft Flow:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I wanted to send the email to the email address that corresponds to the created item. I have to retrieve the email address from another list so that's why I have the "get items". I need to check if the email address is empty and send the email if there is an email address there.